# Write/delete content file text as raw resource android

Tags: android

I make android application that read textfile.txt from resource/raw. And it's work fine. Here is the code:

```
    BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile)));
    String bufferLine;
    String tempText = "";
    try{
        while ((bufferLine = bufferreader.readLine()) != null){
            tempText = tempText + bufferLine;
             }
            } catch (IOException e){
            }
```

Now, I need also to access this raw resource textfile by modify(write) or delete the content. Is there anyway to do it on android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) to store the file after you have modified it.

How you use the external storage depends a bit on what version you are targeting, but it's explained in the documentation that I linked to.

Files that you place in the external storage associated with your application will be deleted if your application is uninstalled and your target version is API level 8 or above.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write resources. Copy the file in the application internal memory or in the external storage (sd card or else) and then you can modify it.

Comment: Oke then I have to create file and copy the content of resource file to memory. Thanks.