# Delete android file located in raw or assets directories

Tags: android, file

I make android application that read file.txt from resource/raw by `context?.resources?.openRawResource(R.raw.file)`, and it's work fine. 
I have tried assets directory by : `context?.assets?.open("file.txt")` and it's work also.

Now, I need to delete this raw/assets resource file or delete the content. Is there anyway to do it with android code?

Comment: look at this...this may help...```https://stackoverflow.com/a/6383529/12273964```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But actually i want to add this file in apk so i have to add it in raw or assets directory, i can't use external/internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to update the Assets or Raw files.

Both of them are **read-only**.

What you can do, it's to make a copy of the file in a writable directory and modify them as needed.

**UPDATE**

Just to give more context, both assets and any resources are part of the binary file (APK or app bundle). As they come as part of the package you cannot change them without creating a new binary.

Comment: The reason why it is readonly is the signature of apk. Any edit action will make it invalid

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Donc actually i have no solution to delete this file from apk with android code ? maybe using another directory ?

Comment: No, it's my opinion. Above i wrote why

Comment: @Vlad I will be interested to read more about the "any edit action will make it invalid", do you have any links?

Comment: With root rights you can edit apk in internal storage, but this will broke app. i have no links, this is my experience